# Bluetooth Pairing with DisplayOnly no passkey box appears

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to configure a bluetooth chip for linux to pair with an android phone. I will have a display on which I am able to show a 6 digit passkey, so I am trying to set the Bluetoothctl agent to DisplayOnly.

According to the table in this post https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/07/11/bt121_-_legacy_pairi-MnCo
If the responder is DisplayOnly, and the initiator (Android) is KeyboardDisplay, it should use Passkey entry, with the responder displaying the code and the initiator entering the code.

What actually happens is the Android shows nothing when attempting to pair, and the bluetoothctl output shows a Numeric Comparison response yes/no: even though I specified I don't have any input (DisplayOnly)

How can I get the bluez agent to actually work as DisplayOnly so it shows a passkey for me to enter on the Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding about pairing options mentioned in the URL are perfect, but BlueZ doesn't work in the same way. To simply the discussion here, please consider the explanation from [Bluetooth Pairing blog](http://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-pairing-part-1-pairing-feature-exchange) from Bluetooth SIG.

To simplify, the below image is copied from the above mentioned blog.

[image]

So input can be three forms "No Input", "Yes/No" and "Keyboard". Output can be "No Output" and "Numeric Output".

In your case, Android is the initiator where you want to enter the passkey which is displayed in responder. So Android device's input is "Keyboard" and responder is "Numeric Output" capable.

To achieve your case, you need to specify "DisplayOnly" in responder (you are already correct) and "KeyboardOnly" or "KeyboardDisplay" in input Android device.

But BlueZ by default doesn't treat "KeyboardDisplay" as a separate option, instead it converts/considers it as "DisplayYesNO", [see here in mgmt.txt API](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n1016) for more details. So your android input device acts as "DisplayYesNo" and results in confusion.

So you need to use "DisplayOnly" at responder and "KeyboardOnly" at initiator end. To experiment this use case with custom agent (not using bluetoothctl's agent), use the below sample example (Note: Not fully implemented, fscanf from stdin is bad :-(, etc.,)

```
/*
 * gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 gio-2.0` -Wall -Wextra -o ./bin/agent ./agent.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0 gio-2.0`
 */
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GMainLoop *loop;
GDBusConnection *con;
#define AGENT_PATH  "/org/bluez/AutoPinAgent"

static void bluez_agent_method_call(GDBusConnection *conn,
                    const gchar *sender,
                    const gchar *path,
                    const gchar *interface,
                    const gchar *method,
                    GVariant *params,
                    GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation,
                    void *userdata)
{
    int pass;
    int entered;
    char *opath;
    GVariant *p= g_dbus_method_invocation_get_parameters(invocation);

    g_print("Agent method call: %s.%s()\n", interface, method);
    if(!strcmp(method, "RequestPinCode")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "DisplayPinCode")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestPasskey")) {
        g_print("Getting the Pin from user: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", &pass);
        g_print("\n");
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, g_variant_new("(u)", pass));
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "DisplayPasskey")) {
        g_variant_get(params, "(ouq)", &opath, &pass, &entered);
        g_print("Path: %s Pass: %d Entered: %d\n", opath, pass, entered);
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, NULL);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestConfirmation")) {
        g_variant_get(params, "(ou)", &opath, &pass);
        g_print("Path: %s Pass: %d\n", opath, pass);
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, NULL);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestAuthorization")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "AuthorizeService")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "Cancel")) {
        ;
    }
    else
        g_print("We should not come here, unknown method\n");
}

static const GDBusInterfaceVTable agent_method_table = {
    .method_call = bluez_agent_method_call,
};

int bluez_register_agent(GDBusConnection *con)
{
    GError *error = NULL;
    guint id = 0;
    GDBusNodeInfo *info = NULL;

    static const gchar bluez_agent_introspection_xml[] =
        "<node name='/org/bluez/SampleAgent'>"
        "   <interface name='org.bluez.Agent1'>"
        "       <method name='Release'>"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestPinCode'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='pincode' direction='out' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='DisplayPinCode'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='pincode' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestPasskey'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='out' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='DisplayPasskey'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='q' name='entered' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestConfirmation'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestAuthorization'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='AuthorizeService'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='uuid' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='Cancel'>"
        "       </method>"
        "   </interface>"
        "</node>";

    info = g_dbus_node_info_new_for_xml(bluez_agent_introspection_xml, &error);
    if(error) {
        g_printerr("Unable to create node: %s\n", error->message);
        g_clear_error(&error);
        return 0;
    }

    id = g_dbus_connection_register_object(con, 
            AGENT_PATH,
            info->interfaces[0],
            &agent_method_table,
            NULL, NULL, &error);
    g_dbus_node_info_unref(info);
    //g_dbus_connection_unregister_object(con, id);
    /* call register method in AgentManager1 interface */
    return id;
}

static int bluez_agent_call_method(const gchar *method, GVariant *param)
{
    GVariant *result;
    GError *error = NULL;

    result = g_dbus_connection_call_sync(con,
            "org.bluez",
            "/org/bluez",
            "org.bluez.AgentManager1",
            method,
            param,
            NULL,
            G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
            -1,
            NULL,
            &error);
    if(error != NULL) {
        g_print("Register %s: %s\n", AGENT_PATH, error->message);
        return 1;
    }

    g_variant_unref(result);
    return 0;
}

static int bluez_register_autopair_agent(const char *cap)
{
    int rc;

    rc = bluez_agent_call_method("RegisterAgent", g_variant_new("(os)", AGENT_PATH, cap));
    if(rc)
        return 1;

    rc = bluez_agent_call_method("RequestDefaultAgent", g_variant_new("(o)", AGENT_PATH));
    if(rc) {
        bluez_agent_call_method("UnregisterAgent", g_variant_new("(o)", AGENT_PATH));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}


static void cleanup_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT) {
        g_print("received SIGINT\n");
        g_main_loop_quit(loop);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int id;
    int rc;

    if(argc < 2)
        return 1;

    if(signal(SIGINT, cleanup_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        g_print("can't catch SIGINT\n");

    con = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL);
    if(con == NULL) {
        g_print("Not able to get connection to system bus\n");
        return 1;
    }

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    id = bluez_register_agent(con);
    if(id == 0)
        goto fail;

    rc = bluez_register_autopair_agent(argv[1]);
    if(rc) {
        g_print("Not able to register default autopair agent\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    g_main_loop_run(loop);

fail:
    g_dbus_connection_unregister_object(con, id);
    g_object_unref(con);
    return 0;
}
```

To experiment this, you must disable agent in bluetoothctl "`agent off`" and turn on the agent as,

```
Responder: ./bin/agent "DisplayOnly"
Initiator: ./bin/agent "KeyboardOnly"
```

When you try to pair from initiator, DisplayPasskey will be called in responder and displays 6 digit PIN and initiator will call RequestPasskey and takes the input PIN from stdin.

Comment: Wow thanks for your long detailed answer. I have been looking at adding a custom agent but the target OS is tinycore, so I am having issues compiling the agents out of the box, but I will keep trying and see if this works!

Comment: @Tyler: Thanks. Accept the answer if it really answers your query :-)

Comment: So I run the custom agent on my responder, but how am I to run it on the initiator if the initiator is an Android? I don't see a way to make the Android Keyboard only, please advise

Comment: @Tyler I am not sure about Android end.

Comment: Ok thanks, I accepted this answer as it answers the issue of why passkey entry is not used, I will open a new question for setting android to Keyboard Only