# Can I change Android device's Bluetooth I/O Capability to "KeyboardOnly"

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an android app I want to use to communicate to a python server on linux over bluetooth, and I have a pairing issue. I want to have the Secure Simple Pairing method of Passkey entry, with the key being displayed on a hardware display for the server, and the input being on the Android phone.

Based on an answer I received from a related question here:

[Bluetooth Pairing with DisplayOnly no passkey box appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192337/bluetooth-pairing-with-displayonly-no-passkey-box-appears)

I would like to change the Android's bluetooth I/O capability to "KeyboardOnly"

According to the link above, when the responder is DisplayOnly, and the initiator has Keyboard, passkey entry pairing is used. This is what I want. However, Bluez automatically converts "KeyboardDisplay" to "DisplayYesNo", as seen here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n1016

This causes issues, as the server tries to do numeric comparison, while I have no clue what Android tries to do, as no dialog pops up at all, no passkey entry or a passkey confirmation.

My question is simply: How do I make the bluetooth settings on my android think the device is "KeyboardOnly", or an alternative is how to configure Bluez to not change "KeyboardDisplay" to "DisplayYesNo"

Comment: did you find the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @manvendra no I did not, I ended up using 'Just works' pairing as a workaround. no  passcode or pin at all

Comment: Any solutions to your issue?