# In the AOSP, set Fluoride's I/O capability to KeyboardOnly

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source

Android's Bluetooth stack Fluoride I/O capability defaults to `DisplayYesNo` for BR/EDR when using Simple Secure Pairing (SSP). But I would like it to default to `KeyboardOnly` instead.

By modifying Fluoride in `system/bt`, what is the correct way of doing that if possible?

---

**What I found so far**

It seems this is defined in [`system/bt/internal_include/bt_target.h`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r37/internal_include/bt_target.h#428):

```
/* The IO capability of the local device (for Simple Pairing) */
#ifndef BTM_LOCAL_IO_CAPS
#define BTM_LOCAL_IO_CAPS BTM_IO_CAP_IO
#endif
```

With `BTM_IO_CAP_IO` meaning `DisplayYesNo` as per [its definition](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r37/stack/include/btm_api_types.h#1305).

Now I want to have Fluoride default to `KeyboardOnly`:

```
#define BTM_LOCAL_IO_CAPS BTM_IO_CAP_IN
```

However with this change Android display a toast like "*Could not pair because of incorrect PIN code*" upon bonding without even showing the popup (whereas the remote device properly reacts to this new I/O capability).

*Related: [Can I change Android device's Bluetooth I/O Capability to “KeyboardOnly”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52211979/2716245).*