# Bluetooth pairing with default passkey set manually in Bluez 5 BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am using Bluez 5.50 stack on a Linux device which does not have a display. I want to pair my device with a Mobile device (Android or IOS) with secure pairing which requires a passkey to connect.
Every time I am trying to pair, an auto generated passkey is being generated. I want to set a default passkey which should be used during the pairing instead of auto-generated passkey.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Probably a [custom agent](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt) is the answer. There should be plenty of answers on here about custom agent in BlueZ. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52192337/7721752 and

Comment: The Agent API fortunatelly follows the Bluetooth spec and randomly generates the passkey for you.

Comment: @emil I was thinking more to set `NoInputNoOutput` on the BlueZ side. Would that not be the way to go for a Linux device with no input or output?

Comment: Yes! That gives you Just Works pairing.

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth standard says that the passkey should be randomly generated and that a static key should not be used. There is a good reason for that: the ad-hoc protocol used in Bluetooth is insecure if the passkey is reused. If you don't have any input or output mechanism, you shall use "Just Works" pairing, which unfortunately does not give you any MITM protection. The security of this is technically more or less the same as when using a static passkey but without giving a false sense of security.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70479911/556495 for an answer to a similar question.